# Strategy for maintaining shared code between projects?

Tags: git, version-control, code-duplication

I have about 5 or 6 projects that use "toolkit" code I've written. The problem I've came across is doing updates to toolkit code; when I do an update I usually need to apply these updates manually to the other projects.

Is there a common strategy for handling this kind of issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules%E2%80%8E).

Create a repository for your "toolkit" code and use it as a submodule for each of
the other projects. To add a submodule, you can do:

`$ git submodule add url_to_repository path_to_local_submodule`

When cloning repositories with submodules, there are another steps required:

`$ git submodule init` and

`$ git submoudule update`

It will fetch the repositories that are submodules and checkout the appropriate
commit of each.